# How do I implement request authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I want to implement request authentication, but this error all the time:

> Error: Argument passed to
>   findByPk is invalid: [object Object]
>       at Function.findByPk (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1714:13)
>       at Function.Model.findById (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:4209:25)
>       at JwtStrategy.passport.use.JwtStrategy [as _verify] (/home/admin/Desktop/project/middleware/passport.js:16:41)
>       at /home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:123:34
>       at /home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:196:12
>       at getSecret (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:76:14)
>       at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:80:10)
>       at Function.module.exports [as JwtVerifier] (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/verify_jwt.js:4:16)
>       at /home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:104:25
>       at JwtStrategy._secretOrKeyProvider (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:40:13)
>       at JwtStrategy.authenticate (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:99:10)
>       at attempt (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:361:16)
>       at authenticate (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:362:7)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
>       at router (/home/admin/Desktop/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)

I use PostgreSQL as a database and Sequelize as ORM.

routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const controller = require('../controllers/user')
const passport = require('passport')


// localhost:5000/api/admin/users
router.get('/users', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), controller.getAll)

module.exports = router
```

passport:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt
const db = require('../config/db.config.js')
const User = db.user


const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), 
    secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
}

module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy(options, async (payload, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await User.findById({
                    where: {
                        id:  payload.id
                    }
                }).select('username id')

                if (user) {
                    done(null, user)
                } else {
                    done(null, false)
                }
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        })
    )
}
```

controller:

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js')
const User = db.user
const errorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler')

module.exports.getAll = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const users = await User.findAll({user: req.user.id})
        res.status(200).json(users)
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(req, e)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your passport code, you are calling `User.findById` and passing a where clause.

I believe it should just be `User.findById(payload.id)`

Comment: I tried it already, but another error occurs `User.findById(...).select is not a function`

Comment: I don't see a `select` method in the docs but you could just use the `toJSON` method to get a simple object and destructure that directly